# merging from trunk to branch accept theirs

Tags: svn

I've been off on vacation for a while and my dead branch has fallen out of date.
I basically want to update my branch without having to bother with any merging conflicts I just want it the same as trunk.

I cant seem to find any example of the syntax. Is this correct ?

`svn merge --accept theirs-full  ^/mycomp/dev/trunk .`

Im on the mac so no tortoise for me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do an update and select tc (theirs-conflict) or just checkout afresh?